# Extracting values from "variable = value" strings with regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string as shown below

```
String1 = aaaa
String2 = bbbb
String4 = cccc
String5 = " 
     abcd;
     bcda
     cdas"
String6 = dddd
```

I need to extract the string after `"="`.
In String 5, I need to extract the string in between double quotes `" "`.
I am able to achieve this using substring and indexof.
How can I achieve this in Perl regex?

Comment: You should show your Perl code, and we can show you what you did wrong.

Comment: You could treat this as a *really* weird form of a CSV file (using `=` as the delimiter and ignoring whitespace around it). I don't do Perl, but I'm sure there's something to handle CSV files, isn't there?

Comment: `Text::ParseWords` can handle this.

Comment: I tried with substring and indexof Function. I am not sure of doing it in regex, so that is my primary question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RegEx: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s*=\s*([^"']+?$|"[^"]+|'[^']+)/gm`

This also takes care of both cases with single and double quotes and also simple values.

**Text to be matched:**

```
String1 = aaaa  
String2 = bbbb  
String4 = cccc  
String5 = "   
     abcd;  
     bcda  
     cdas"  
String6 = dddd  
String7 = '   
     abcd;  
     bcda  
     cdas'
```

**Matches:**

```
MATCH 1 `aaaa`
MATCH 2 `bbbb`
MATCH 3 `cccc`
MATCH 4 `" ↵     abcd;↵     bcda↵     cdas`
MATCH 5 `dddd`
MATCH 6 `' ↵     abcd;↵     bcda↵     cdas`
```

Demo link: http://regex101.com/r/dL4cS3

Comment: would be interesting to know why I got a downvote for a working solution to this answer...